# How to insert a random noise to a signal

Tags: matlab, random, noise

I have a random signal and I would like to add a random noise to it.

I can add noise to standard signals like Sine, Cosine, Square, sawtooth etc.. by using `awgn` or `randn`

But this doesn't work when I try to add the same noise on a random signal like `signal = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10];`

These are the two approaches which I tried:

```
signal = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10 10]; %original signal
plot(signal)
sigma = 0.07; %noise standard deviation
noisy = signal + sigma*randn(size(signal)); %noisy signal
plot(noisy)
```

OR

```
signal = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10 10];
s = awgn(signal,10,'measured');
plot([signal s])
```

How can I add noise to these random signals? and why can't I accomplish this task by using standard commands?

Comment: Is it normal that your sigma is so small compare to the signal ?

Comment: How and by the way what do you mean by "It doesn't work" ?

Comment: @obchardon : You can vary the sigma as much as you want the value of sigma doesn't matter, since I just need a random noise overlapped on the original signal. Since I am new on stack overflow and my reputation is just '5', therefore I couldn't add any images to support my question.

Comment: But I mean, your code is right, it's working.

Comment: By all I see, it should work. Only you may not see this on your plot, because 0.07 is not visible when you have range of signal from 10 to 200. Try zooming, and then try changing your noise sigma to something observable, like 20.
Maybe you are mislead by the fact that you use plot() function which draw straight lines between points? If you think there is not diffrence then try:

`signal = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10 10];
plot(signal);
hold on; % to stop newer plots overwrite previous ones
sigma = 10;
noisy = signal+sigma*randn(size(signal));
plot(noisy,'r');
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question you want to add some noise to your signal with a smaller interval than the sampling frequency of the signal itself.

In this case you can use `interp1` in order to interpolate your signal:

```
signal   = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10];
n        = length(signal);
sinterp  = interp1(1:n,signal,1:0.1:n); %interpolation of your signal with interp1(x,y,new_x)
sigma    = 10; %a bigger sigma so we can observe the noise.
noisy    = sinterp + sigma*randn(size(sinterp));
plot(1:n,signal,'b',1:0.1:n,noisy,'r')
```

Comment: Thank you.. This is exactly what I wanted. But how can I apply the same logic to, say 3 signal like `a = [00 00 20 20 00 00 40 40 40 00 00 55 55 38 00];
b = [00 00 70 70 50 50 50 70 70 100 100 120 120 00 00];
c = [200 180 160 120 80 80 70 70 65 50 55 120 10 10 10];`

Comment: If you need to use several time the same part of code: create a function !